# php replace some strings between tags or chars

Tags: php, json, regex, replace

I need to replace some text in a string. I think an example can explain better:

[myFile.json]

```
{ "Dear":"newString1", "an example string":"newString2" }
```

[example.php]

```
$myString = "@Dear@ name, this is @an example string@.";

function gimmeNewVal($myVal){
    $obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('myFile.json'));
    return $obj->$myVal;
}

echo gimmeNewVal("Dear"); // This print "newString1"
```

So, what I need is to find any strings between the '@' symbol and for each string found I need to replace using the gimmeNewVal() function.

I already tried with preg_* functions but I'm not very able with regex...

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: where are you using `$myString` ?

Comment: If you actually need to use regular expressions for this: http://regex101.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all` to match all strings of type `@somestring@` using regex `@([^@]+)@` and then iterate over a for loop to do the replacement of each such found string in the original string to replace with the actual value from your function `gimmeNewVal` which returns the value from your given json.

Here is the PHP code for same,

```
$myString = "@Dear@ name, this is @an example string@.";

function gimmeNewVal($myVal){ // I've replaced your function from this to make it practically runnable so you can revert this function as posted in your post
    $obj = json_decode('{ "Dear":"newString1", "an example string":"newString2" }');
    return $obj->$myVal;
}

preg_match_all('/@([^@]+)@/', $myString, $matches);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    echo $matches[1][$i].' --> '.gimmeNewVal($matches[1][$i])."\n";
    $myString = preg_replace('/'.$matches[0][$i].'/',gimmeNewVal($matches[1][$i]), $myString);

}
echo "\nTransformed myString: ".$myString;
```

Prints the transformed string,

```
Dear --> newString1
an example string --> newString2

Transformed myString: newString1 name, this is newString2.
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback function

```
$myString = "@Dear@ name, this is @an example string@.";

$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('myFile.json'));

echo preg_replace_callback('/@([^@]+)@/', 
        function ($x) use($obj) { return isset($obj->{$x[1]}) ? $obj->{$x[1]} : ''; }, 
        $myString);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8e4a286ec0c0f2292bad06be9c225eb4dee4228)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [T-Regx tool](https://t-regx.com):

```
pattern('@([^@])@')->replace($input)->all()->by()->map([
    '@Dear@' => "newString1", 
    '@an example string@' => 'newString2'
]);
```

or

```
pattern('@([^@])@')->replace($input)->all()->group(1)->by()->map([
    'Dear' => "newString1", 
    'an example string' => 'newString2'
]);
```

---

You can also use methods `by()->map()`, `by()->mapIfExists()` or `by()->mapDefault()`. Whatever you need :)